# SQL 'as' Statement Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having difficulty with the SQL 'as' statement. Based on what I've read and seen on YouTube, the 'as' or alias command can be used to rename columns.

Error:

> System.Exception: Invalid object name 'Capprogram'
>   select main1.id as captempCaseMgmtMain_id , CapSSMatrix.Name as captempCaseMgmtMain_idSSMatrix , CapSSMatrix.datefrom as Date , CapSSMatrix.dateto as DateTo , Person.lastname +' , '+Person.firstname as Name , main1.date as captempCaseMgmtMain_id , Capprogram.program as captempCaseMgmtMain_idProgram from captempCaseMgmtMain main1 left join captempCaseMgmtMain main2 on main2.ssmgroup = main1.ssmgroup and main2.type = 3 JOIN CapSSMatrix on main1.idSSMatrix = CapSSMatrix.id JOIN Person on Person.id = main1.familymember JOIN Capprogram on capprogram.id = main1.idprogram where main1.type = 1 and isnumeric(main2.id)<> 1 and ((getdate() > capSSMatrix.dateto) ) and CapSSMatrix.id = '' order by main1.id desc at IMSE.UI.BaseEnginePage.GetDBValues() at IMSE.UI.Pages.Aspx_Pages.LoadPage() at IMSE.UI.Pages.Aspx_Pages.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

This is the command/query I've tried. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
    main1.id AS captempCaseMgmtMain_id,
    CapSSMatrix.Name AS captempCaseMgmtMain_idSSMatrix, 
    CapSSMatrix.datefrom AS Date, 
    CapSSMatrix.dateto AS DateTo,
    Person.lastname + ', ' + Person.firstname AS Name,
    main1.date AS captempCaseMgmtMain_id,
    Capprogram.program AS captempCaseMgmtMain_idProgram
FROM 
    captempCaseMgmtMain main1
LEFT JOIN 
    captempCaseMgmtMain main2 ON main2.ssmgroup = main1.ssmgroup 
                              AND main2.type = 3
JOIN 
    CapSSMatrix ON main1.idSSMatrix = CapSSMatrix.id
JOIN 
    Person ON Person.id = main1.familymember
JOIN 
    Capprogram ON capprogram.id = main1.idprogram
WHERE
    main1.type = 1 AND
    ISNUMERIC(main2.id) <> 1 AND
    (GETDATE() > capSSMatrix.dateto) AND
    CapSSMatrix.id = $CapSSMatrix.id
ORDER BY
    main1.id DESC
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with aliasing. I think this is because you don't have a table or view called `Capprogram`. Maybe it only has one p.

Comment: If your query is in a different schema then where the table resides, you need to qualify it with the schema name. Its a good practice to qualify it with schema name always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error suggests there is no object named Capprogram which I only see referenced in your join clause. I would confirm that this table exists and, if it does, use the fully qualified name.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your table is not there in the schema. Find your table schema name by below query.

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='tableName'
```

Then try to put schemaname.tablename

Also make sure that table is present in the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

This code produces the following error:

> Msg 126, Level 15, State 1, Line 24 Invalid pseudocolumn
>   "$CapSSMatrix".

This is because your `$CapSSMatrix.id` contains `$` and server thinks it's a pseudocolumn, but it is not.

So if it's a table name, it should be quoted like this: `[$CapSSMatrix]`, and if it's not just remove this `$`

Comment: You are asking a question, then do it in a comment. This is not an answer.

Answer (score -3):

you have to add LEFT JOIN to the table for example:

```
1- left join captempCaseMgmtMain main2
2- left join CapSSMatrix
3- left join Person
4- left join Capprogram
```